# go through files and OCR pdf

Tags: pdf, ocr

Is there free way to go though bunch of pdf image only files and folders (in different location) and OCR them?

I would be really interested it... please suggest..

Comment: this is borderline off-topic here... it might be better for you to post it on superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [VietOCR](http://vietocr.sf.net), which monitors a watch folder for new input images. The program requires GhostScript to recognize PDF format.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend OCRvision [OCR PDF software](https://www.ocrvision.com). It has OCR folder watch where you can configure any folder as a monitored folder and the software will auto-OCR the PDF files there and convert any new scanned documents to searchable PDF.  You can download the software from the web site.

PS:- I work for OCrvision